# Bind ObservableCollections Property from other Property in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection, datatemplate

I'm having a Property of type `ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>` and one more Property of type `string`, it represents the **Name** of the `MobileModelInfo` Model.

I need to bind the Property in `DataTemplate` using `MobileProperty` property for looping `MobileList` property.

If the `MobileProperty` property is "**Name**", then the `ListBox` should display Name of `MobileModelInfo` in the `ObservableCollection`

If the `MobileProperty` property is "**Catagory**", then the `ListBox` should display Catagory of `MobileModelInfo` in the `ObservableCollection`

Model:

```
public class MobileModelInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Catagory { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

View Model:

```
public class MobileViewModel{
    private ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo> _mobileList;
    public ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo> MobileList
    {
        get { return _mobileList; }
        set { _mobileList = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private string _mobileProperty;
    public string MobileProperty
    {
        get { return _mobileProperty; }
        set { _mobileProperty= value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public MobileViewModel()
    {
        MobileList = ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>();
        MobileList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "iPhone 4", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2011" });
        MobileList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "iPhone 5", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2013" });
        MobileList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "iPhone 6", Catagory = "Premium Smart Phone", Year = "2015" });

        MobileProperty = "Name"; 
    }
}
```

The XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding MobileList}" x:Name="iListBox" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" />
            </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Kindly assist me... How to Bind the Property ?

Answer (score 0):

I use https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged
For bind any models i use 
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
and all